# erlang vs golang

Tags: concurrency, erlang, go

I intend to learn a new language for better concurrency.

Erlang is a old but powerful language with a runtime to support its whole concurrency system as well as a well-known library, OTP. This is more like JVM.

Go is another language good at concurrency, while it's more like C.

My major field is about C/S and B/S. What should I prefer?

Comment: Learn both. It'll do you good.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-nuts/TbVZNLbvZlY